# Why is the binomial distribution's likelihood function equal to $p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

So for $X \sim  Bin(n, p)$ I calculate the likelihood function

using formula $\ell(\pi ) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} p(X = x_i)$

$$\ell(\pi) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} {n \choose x_i}p^{x_i}(1-p)^{n-x_i}$$

$$= \prod_{i=1}^{n} {n \choose x_i} p^{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}(1-p)^{n^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}$$

Not sure how this simplifies to  $p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$?

Comment: Why are you using the likelihood function instead of the log-likelihood function?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean

Comment: $x\mapsto\log x$ is a monotone increasing function, so maximizing the log of the likelihood function is equivalent to maximizing the likelihood function itself. Generally the log-likelihood function is easier to work with because taking logs turns products into sums.

Comment: I'm looking to derive the likelihood function though

Comment: Presumably you are doing so in order to compute the maximum-likelihood estimator. In this case there is no reason not to use the log-likelihood function.